# AddThis Dynamic URLs

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

I do a POST to some external site, that site spits out a URL, which I truncate using bit.ly.  I want to somehow get that URL and use it for the custom URL fields in AddThis.

Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [jQuery ajax methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to get the url

Answer (score 0):

I would render the button with javascript after the AJAX call returns the URL

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#rendering-js

This snippet should get you started:

```
addthis.button(document.getElementById('my-button'), {  }, { url: bitlyUrl });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of the above solutions and none worked for me, went with something like this `$('.addthis_toolbar').attr('addthis:url', 'http://google.com');`

For this to work you'll need the AddThis div to look like this

`<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style share-bar" addthis:url="">`